# How to create a new column based upon different boolean criteria for individual columns in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, boolean-logic

I want to create a binary column that flags  yes if exactly one column in the dataframe meets logical condition A and another column in the dataframe meets either logical condition A or logical condition B. So the new column will only have a 1 if two separate columns satisfy the conditions above.

Each column is a separate product count for each year.
Condition A : If a product  (i.e. "c1") sold 8 products in the current year, between 1 and 6 the previous year and between 1 and 6 the year before that (2 years ago) Condition A is meet.
Condition B: if any other product (i.e. not "c1" say "c3") met condition A above OR sold 8 in current year and 8 the previous year and 8 two years ago condition B is met.
So Success can only be 1 if exactly any 2 of the columns in a particular year meet the conditions above. One column must meet condition A and another column condition B.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'C1':[7,3,2,8,3,4,6,8,3,2],'C2':[2,5,4,8,8,8,3,2,8,4],'C3': [7,5,4,6,7,8,6,8,1,7],
                   'C4':[3,4,4,6,4,2,6,3,2,6],'C5':[6,4,0,8,4,2,6,6,7,8],'Year':[2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,2019]})
df.set_index('Year', inplace=True)
df1 =df[::-1]
df1
_1_CorrA =((df1.eq(8)) & (df1.shift(-1).isin([1,6])) & (df1.shift(-2).isin([1,6]))).sum(axis=1)==1

_1_CorrB =(((df1.eq(8)) & (df1.shift(-1).eq(8)) & (df1.shift(-2).eq(8))) |
              ((df1.eq(8)) & (df1.shift(-1).isin([1,6])) & (df1.shift(-2).isin([1,6])))).sum(axis=1)==1


Strategy = (((_1_CorrA) & (_1_CorrB)))

df1['Success']=np.where(Strategy,1,0)
```

[image: Expected Results]
I expect to see 1 in index row 2015 and 2013, because these are the only two rows  where exactly two different columns meet the conditions above.

Comment: Does your code work? What's your question?

Comment: Can you explain why 2015 is a "Success". It doesn't appear to meet the logical conditions,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Success means either exactly two columns meet condition A (`a.sum(1).eq(2)`) or one column meets condition A and another meets B whereby the current year and each of the prior two years equal the target value of 8.

In order to ensure the same column does not meet both condition A and condition B, I get the successful column from condition A and ensure it is not equal to the successful column from condition B (`a.idxmax(1).ne(b.idxmax(1))`). This comparison is only made when there is exactly one success from both condition A and condition B, hence why I can use `idxmax` to get the column that passed the condition.

```
target = 8 
upper_limit = 6
lower_limit = 1
df1_shift1 = df1.shift(-1)
df1_shift2 = df1.shift(-2)

a = (
    df1.eq(target) 
    & df1_shift1.ge(lower_limit) 
    & df1_shift1.le(upper_limit) 
    & df1_shift2.ge(lower_limit) 
    & df1_shift2.le(upper_limit)
)
b = (
    df1.eq(target)
    & df1_shift1.eq(target)
    & df1_shift2.eq(target)
)
success = (
    a.sum(1).eq(2) 
    | (a.sum(1).eq(1) 
       & b.sum(1).eq(1) 
       & a.idxmax(1).ne(b.idxmax(1)))
)
>>> df1.assign(Success=success)
      C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  Success
Year                             
2019   2   4   7   6   8    False
2018   3   8   1   2   7    False
2017   8   2   8   3   6    False
2016   6   3   6   6   6    False
2015   4   8   8   2   2    False
2014   3   8   7   4   4    False
2013   8   8   6   6   8     True
2012   2   4   4   4   0    False
2011   3   5   5   4   4    False
2010   7   2   7   3   6    False
```

Comment: I am just getting to this answer. I haven't tried your solution yet, but your approach is more important to me, because there will be a series of logical problems coming down the pike in which  I will have to adopt some variation of the solution you gave.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the `DataFrame.apply()` to help you.

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'C1':[7,3,2,8,3,4,6,8,3,2], 
                   'C2':[2,5,4,8,8,8,3,2,8,4], 
                   'C3': [7,5,4,6,7,8,6,8,1,7],  
                   'C4':[3,4,4,6,4,2,6,3,2,6], 
                   'C5':[6,4,0,8,4,2,6,6,7,8], 
                   'Year':[2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,2019]})

def my_rule(row):
    C1 = row['C1']
    C2 = row['C2']
    C3 = row['C3']
    C4 = row['C4']
    C5 = row['C5']
    year = row['year']

    # write your rule of C1,...,C5 here
    if ...:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

df['Success'] = df.apply(lambda row: my_rule(row), axis=1)
```

Hope this fit your question.

Comment: Thank you I am sorry I am late commenting on this. My computer suddenly went dark. I will try your approach and will comment back if it is helpful.